# Angular Guard: Where to redirect when user is not authorized?

Tags: angular, typescript, authorization, router

According to Angular docs, the `CanActivate` interface exposes [a function](https://v5.angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) that returns a boolean. The official example shows the function is like a predicate with no side effects.

We want to prevent the user from accessing the page directly from the URL.
According to [an example in this article](https://gnomeontherun.com/2017/03/02/guards-and-login-redirects-in-angular/) and many example online including StackOverflow answers, it is possible to add a call to the Angular router from within the `canActivate()` function.

However I do not know if this is considered good practice as it appears to be a side effect.

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private keycloakService : KeycloakService,
              private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.keycloakService.isAdmin()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/']); // HERE
    return false;
  }
}
```

What is the recommended way to redirect the user away from a guarded page if they access it directly from an URL?

Comment: Even if someone tries to access a guarded page directly via URL, they have to go through the guard. Hence there won't be any issue.

Comment: If you want you can display a modal that informs user he is not unauthorized to access the page, and then redirect him (when he closes or clicks 'ok' on modal's button)